# Include 500 file if PHP errors are found

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible, using PHP, to show a 500 page if I accidently make a mistake in my code? I tried using `error_reporting(0)` but that will just hide the errors. And if I use htaccess' `php_flag display_errors off` Chrome (and other browsers) will just display a 500 error like this one: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4c87df1998634097a18a85d268ccc818.png

Thanks :)

Comment: Just for clarification sake: You want to display a page if a 500 error occurs?

Comment: General rule: If you get a 500 error, your FIRST thing to check is the server's error log to get detailsa bout the 500.

Comment: @Fairy No, I want to display a 500 page if I make a mistake in my PHP code so users don't see PHP warnings. I know I can just hide them but I prefer to show a useful 500 page instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5.x you can catch all errors except fatals. Just look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Quick example:

```
<?php 
function handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
   echo file_get_contents('500.html');
   die();
}
set_error_handler('handler', E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Combianate these functions to make a redirect on error:

`error_get_last()` #  to get the lasterror

`header()` # to rediect if needed

`register_shutdown_function()` # to catch errors with error_get_last

`ob_start() / ob_flush()`# catch content, for late showing or not

At start of your php file:

```
ob_start();
register_shutdown_function(function(){
   $err = error_get_last();
   //check the $err 
   if($err){
      header('Location: 505.html');
      exit;
   } else {
      ob_flush();#or ob_end_flush();
      exit;
   }
});
```

You can also catch fatal errors with this.

Comment: Thanks for this! But can it also catch parse errors?

Comment: `parse errors` if you means php code parse errors: nope. compiling is before executing and while compiling it checks for errors in the syntax

Comment: php_check_syntax ( string $filename [, string &$error_message ] )

Answer (score 0):

Any webserver (apache/nginx/lighttpd) let you do custom error pages

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/4639

But do not forget to turn off PHP error display, just log them.